# Sending Image via Socket IO, Image not getting sent

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, sockets, express

I have a Chat Application where we can chat anonymously. I am trying to add functionality for sending images. I don't understand why my code is not working Can somebody have a look at it and help me in rectifying the mistake that I have made.

```js
var app = require('express')();          
                                         
var http = require('http').Server(app);
                                                        
var io =require ('socket.io')(http);

var path = require('path');
var people = {};

//Initialize appication with path of the application
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var express=require('express');
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../Chat', 'index.html'));
});

// Socket Connection Events
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('Chat Message', function(from, msg){
    io.emit('Chat Message', from, msg);
  });
  socket.on('user image', function (from,msg) {
        //Received an image: broadcast to all
        socket.broadcast.emit('user image', from, msg);
    });
  socket.on('UserNotification', function(user){
    io.emit('UserNotification', user);
  });
   socket.on('add user', function(user){
    socket.userName=user;
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function (user) {
io.emit('User left', {user:socket.userName});console.log(socket.userName);
});
  
  
});

 
// Listen application request on port 3000
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on ***:3000');
});
```

*chat.js:*

```js
var socket = io();
$(document).ready(function(){
  var name = generateID();
  $('#user').val(name);
  socket.emit('Chat Message', 'System_User','<b>' + name + '</b> has joined the discussion');
  socket.emit('add user', name);
   });
   
$('#imagefile').bind('change', function(e){
      var data = e.originalEvent.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(evt){
        image('me', evt.target.result);
        socket.emit('user image', evt.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(data);
      
    });
 
 socket.on('user image', image);

function image (from, base64Image) {
    $('#messages').append('<li><b style="color:' + color + '">' + from + '</b>: ' + '<img src="' + base64Image + '"/>' + '</li>');
}

function generateID() {
  var nameID = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
 
  for( var j=0; j < 5; j++ ) {
    nameID += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return nameID;
}
function submitFunc(){
  var from = $('#user').val();
  var message = $('#m').val();
  if(message != '') {
  socket.emit('Chat Message', from, message);
}
$('#m').val('').focus();
  return false;
}
 
function showTyping() {
  var user = $('#user').val();
  socket.emit('UserNotification', user);
}
 
socket.on('Chat Message', function(from, msg){
  var me = $('#user').val();
  var color = (from == me) ? 'red' : 'violet';
  var from = (from == me) ? 'Me' : from;
  $('#messages').append('<li><b style="color:' + color + '">' + from + '</b>: ' + msg + '</li>');
});
 
socket.on('UserNotification', function(user){
  var me = $('#user').val();
  if(user != me) {
    $('#UserNotification').text(user + ' is typing ...');
  }
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#UserNotification').text(''); }, 10000);;
});

socket.on('User left', function(user){


$('#UserNotification').text(user.user + ' is disconnected');

});
```

*style.css:*

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font: 16px Papyrus, ComicSans; }
form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 70%; }
form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
form #button { color:#F5FBEF; background: #2E2EFE; border: none; padding: 10px;  width: 9%; }
#messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
#messages li:nth-child(even) { background: #F3F781; }
#UserNotification{ position: fixed; bottom: 42px; width: 100%; }
#twitterFeed { position:relative;
left:80px;
    width:33.333%;
    height:800px;
   float:right; }
   
  div.filebutton {
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: -7px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px !important;
}

.filebutton input#imagefile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

*index.html:*

```html
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Chat App - Random ID Generation</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'/>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="chat.js"></script>
 <script>
 !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    </script> 
 </head>
  <body>
  <div id ="ChatContainer">
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <span id="UserNotification"></span>
    <form id="form" action="" onsubmit="return submitFunc();" >
      <input type="hidden" id="user" value="" /><input id="m" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="showTyping();" placeholder="Type your message here.." /><input type="submit" id="button" value="Send"/>
  
 </form>
 <div id = "twitterFeed">
 <section>
   <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/jitesh_y" data-widget-id="671505342530998272">Tweets by @jitesh_y</a>

    </section>
 </div>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may have to be more specific about the problems you're having, I'm not sure anyone will want to sift through that to find the answer for you.

Comment: I am sorry for long post but I wanted to put everything on table so that it is easy to understand.

Comment: A minimal example that demonstrates the problem is much easier to understand than a full program with a lot of unrelated code mixed in.